# Giving x and y labels, titles and legends to individual histograms in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am new to using histogram in Python
I want to display 11 histograms by selecting 11 columns from data frame.
Instead of using a subplot, can I have xlabel, ylabel, legend and title for each of these histograms?

```
df.hist(column=['c1','c2','c3',.......'c11'], figsize=(20,20))
```

All the columns have different scales.
If can not be done using one hist() how can I do it using subplot?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

In this case `df.hist()` returns a 2D array of axes (each ax refers to one of the subplots). You can iterate through these axes and set individual xlabels, ylabels, titles and legends.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({f'c{i}': np.random.randn(100) * i for i in range(1, 12)})
axes = df.hist(column=[f'c{i}' for i in range(1, 12)], figsize=(20, 20), label='histogram')
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel(), start=1):
    if i <= 11:
        ax.set_xlabel(f'xlabel for column c{i}')
        ax.set_ylabel(f'ylabel for column c{i}')
        ax.set_title(f'title for column c{i}')
        ax.legend(title=f'legend for column c{i}')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Instead of Title for Column1 using df.columns how can I add column name directly instead of indexes like 1,2 ? I tried this:  axes = white_wine_quality.hist(column=[f'{i}' for i in white_wine_quality.columns[i]], figsize=(20, 20), label='histogram')
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel(), start=1):
    if i < (white_wine_quality.columns.size-1):
        ax.set_xlabel('Number of Samples')
        ax.set_ylabel('Number of Samples')
        ax.set_title(f'title for column {i}')
        ax.legend(title=f'legend for column {i}')
plt.show()

Comment: Please edit your original question and add your additional code properly formatted.  The comments are not meant for adding code.